# Is there a way to redirect all traffic from HTTP to HTTPS on my MeteorJS app deployed on Heroku?

Tags: heroku, meteor

Basically what the title says ;).

I've seen an npm package for Express (https://www.npmjs.org/package/heroku-ssl-redirect), but not for MeteorJS.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming you have configured SSL this package should come handy

```
meteor add force-ssl
```

It worked on 0.9.4, I'm not sure it's working now

Comment: Thanks! It worked great on Heroku. Linf to package: https://atmospherejs.com/meteor/force-ssl

Comment: This is very useful but this also requires the proxy in front of the app, sets the x-forwarded-proto=http/https in order to work propertly